# localstorage on Internet Explorer not working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

localstorage seems to work on:
- Google Chrome
- Mozilla Firefox
- Opera
- Opera mini
- probably Safari

but not on internet explorer (I'm using internet explorer 11). My is is windows 7.
I need something equivalent that will do the same job. This is for a project and I'm doing everything on my C: drive (security is not important) so my protocol is file:\. I've done some research and some people got it fixed by adding:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

but it didn't work for me.

here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Login</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <style type="text/css">
                * {
                    font-family:Cambria;
                    color:blue;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                function transfer() {
                    confirm("Would you like to save your password for this site?");
                    var contents = document.getElementById('email_input').value;
                    var contents_2 = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
                    localStorage.setItem('user', contents);
                    localStorage.setItem('password', contents_2);
                    window.location.href = 'page2.html';
                    };

                var button_clicked = function(){
                    email_content = document.getElementById("email_input").value;
                    pass_content = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
                    points = 0;
                    if (email_content.length < 1){
                        document.getElementById("empty_1").innerHTML = ("*please input your email address");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("empty_1").innerHTML = ("<br>");
                        points += 1;
                    };
                    if (pass_content.length < 1){
                        document.getElementById("empty_2").innerHTML = ("*please input your password");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("empty_2").innerHTML = ("<br>");
                        points += 1;
                    };
                    if (points === 2){
                        transfer();
                    }
                };

            </script>
            <div id="top_bar" style="height:100px;background-color:lightslategray;">
                <marquee scrollamount="20" behavior="scroll"><p style="font-size:30px;color:white;">
                    Welcome, please login to your account to continue</p>
                </marquee>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="margin-left:500px;width:300px;height:200px;background-color:lightblue;"></div>    
                <div style="margin-left:440px;">
                    <div style="background-color:whitesmoke;width:350px;height:270px;margin-left:30px;border-radius:15px;
                         margin-bottom:30px;">
                            <div style="margin-left:40px;">
                                <h1>Login below</h1>
                                <p id="empty_1" style="color:red;"><br></p>
                                <p>Email address: <input id="email_input" type="text" style="width:150px;"/></p>
                                <p id="empty_2" style="color:red;"><br></p>
                                <p>Password: <input id="password_input" type="password" style="width:180px;"/></p>
                                <br>
                                <button onclick="button_clicked()">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:500px;width:300px;height:500px;background-color:lightblue;"></div>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

saved as page1.html
and second page is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title id='title'>title goes here</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <style type='text/css'>
                h1 {
                    color:blue;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id='my_title'>Title</h1>
            <h2 id='my_pass'>Title</h2>
            <script>
                var full_name = localStorage.getItem('user');
                list = [];
                for (i=0;i<full_name.length;i++){
                    if (full_name[i]==="@"){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        list.push(full_name[i]);
                    }
                };
                document.getElementById("my_title").innerHTML = ("Name: " + list.join(""));
                var full_pass = localStorage.getItem('password');
                document.getElementById("my_pass").innerHTML = ("Email address: " + full_name);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

saved as page2.html

All answers appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of IE?

Comment: what is the os you are using?

Comment: If you are using IE 11 make sure its patched to the latest version (windows update) as there was a bug in the initial release with Win7 SP1 and local storage was not working as intended. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21156133/3535297

Comment: "Help" / "About Internet Explorer" will tell you what version you're running.

Comment: @Wolfdog to check your IE version click around the menus at the top of the browser until you see something that says "About Internet Explorer", i cant tell you exactly where that is because i dont know what version you are using

Comment: also, you might want to think about another option besides `<marquee>` it is non-standard is is not recommended for use as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding the doctype declaration means your mark-up is resolved by the browser the way it should (i.e. as HTML5).

Internet Explorer has a couple of issues with local storage. First of all, it doesn't work at all in versions prior to 8 -- you don't specify the version you're running in your post.

**Important**: you mention you are running on your C: drive: does this mean you are using the `file://` protocol rather than http? if so, problem solved. Using the file protocol will cause various issues, *not least that `localStorage` simply won't work in IE*.

If you're still having issues, you *may* find you need to tinker with the browser's security settings to allow local storage.

This page includes a matrix detailing localStorage support in the various browsers:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Be sure to check out Mark Pilgrim's excellent HTML5 resource, which includes some IE-specific code for detecting the `storage` event:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Is that localStorage is `undefined` for documents opened with file protocol somehow related to a `document.domain` being equal to empty string in such case?

Comment: You mentioned `localStorage` not working pior to 8. Does `sessionStorage` also not work in IE versions prior to 9?

Comment: As of IE11 it is possible to use localStorage over `file:` - see the answers to [localStorage object is undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie).

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

I tried with IE 11 , that working for me!