# Local Storage and IE. Can't make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I am trying to keep checkboxes checked on refresh with localStorage. All modern browsers do the job except IE11 (and lower)

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/usme91gk/

```
(function() {
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var box = boxes[i];
    if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
        setupBox(box);
    }
}

function setupBox(box) {
    var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
    var oldVal    = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
    console.log(oldVal);
    box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;

    box.addEventListener("change", function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked); 
    });
}
})();
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to somehow adapt this to IE? Or maybe you know a script that keeps checkboxes checked on refresh in all browsers? (Doesn't matter if it's in javascript or jquery). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To keep checkbox `checked`, **checked** property will help..

Comment: I am aware of that. How is it relatable to what I am asking though?

Comment: LocalStorage should work fine in IE 8+. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23391501/1124565), it may have what you're looking for

Comment: I just ran your fiddle on Windows 8.1, IE 11.0.9600.17498 and it worked correctly. Maybe you have a version of IE that is out of date or you have security settings that aren't permitting the use of LocalStorage

Comment: @qwikad, I got it wrong initially. You can use `cookies` over localStorage if lower versions of IF is your concern.

Comment: @RayonDabre I searched the web for an hour looking for a good one that uses cookies. Came here to see if maybe someone has one.

Comment: By the way is there a way to add a function to the script above that supports cookies? Just to cover some IEs and older FFs.

Answer (score 0):

I use jstorage when I need localstorage. It has some added features like TTL (time to live).

http://www.jstorage.info