# HTML5 local storage broken in ie11 win 8.1 x64 ? error: function expected

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Anyone else seeing this can't find any info, previously has been fixed in a patch ages ago, anyone else seeing this ?

```
localStorage.setItem("hello", "somedata");
alert(localStorage.getItem("hello"));
localStorage.clear();
```

ie version 11.0.0600.17107, update version 11.0.8 (KB2953522)

Tested in chrome work's perfectly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155137/javascript-localstorage-object-broken-in-ie11-on-windows-7

Comment: apparently fixed in a patch in 11.0.2 - KB2898785 currently i'm in 11.0.8, thanks for looking

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/61177c2b-6a38-4207-9cbe-ccd6c86b1d42/html5-local-storage-broken-in-ie11-win-81-x64-error-function-expected?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still being caught by this problem: in my case, I had to reset the entire Internet Explorer:

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab

Under Reset Internet Explorer Settings, click the button "Reset..."