# localStorage property not coming in IE11 on specific my html page

Tags: javascript

I have created html page using dreamweaver software.

I don't get list of properties of localStorage/SessionStorage in developer tools in IE11 browser.

On debugging www.google.com, I get all these properties but not getting on my html page.

Please do the needful.

Comment: Post what are you trying (code)

Comment: Maybe of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155137/javascript-localstorage-object-broken-in-ie11-on-windows-7

Comment: _“Please do the needful”_ – and you please go read [ask] first.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage won't work with a `file://` URL.

You need to view your your Dreamweaver page with an `http://` URL.

You could publish the page to a real server. Or you could set up a server on your local computer. Here are a couple of ways that I have used:

1. Enable IIS on your computer. *Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services* . Don't enable FTP Server. Then, *Computer > Manage > Services and Applications > Internet Information Services > Sites* . Then add a site, with Bindings to localhost:81 and Basic Settings to point to the root of your Dreamweaver project. Now you can view your page as `http://localhost:81/mypage.html`.
2. Install Microsoft Expression Web (a free alternative to Dreamweaver) and view the page from within Expression Web using its built-in Development Server feature. The software starts up a little webserver in the background, bound to a port on localhost.  (FWIW, It even supports PHP.)