# localStorage Not Clearing in Any Browser Outside of Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm having an issue when it comes to the localStorage clearing in any browser environment outside of Chrome. I have a captcha using shapes that the user must draw to submit a form. There is a `span` the user can click to generate a new shape. In order to keep the information inputted into the previous fields, I store the data in localStorage every time a new shape is requested. However, if the page is refreshed, I'd like the localStorage to be completely wiped out.

Here is the code for the `span` that the user clicks on:

```
<span style="color:#0000EE;cursor:pointer;" id="new-shape" onclick="window.location.reload()" title="Click for a new shape">new shape</span>
```

And here is the JS for the localStorage:

```
$('#new-shape').on('click', function () {
    var stickies = $('.sticky');
    var dropdowns = $('select');

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        localStorage.setItem("branch", $('#00NL0000003INTJ').val());
        localStorage.setItem("department", $('#00NL0000003I0Ux').val());
        localStorage.setItem("contact", $('#00NL0000003INUC').val());

        localStorage.setItem("company", stickies[0].value);
        localStorage.setItem("firstName", stickies[1].value);
        localStorage.setItem("lastName", stickies[2].value);
        localStorage.setItem("phone", stickies[3].value);
        localStorage.setItem("ext", stickies[4].value);
        localStorage.setItem("email", stickies[5].value);
        localStorage.setItem("help", stickies[6].value);
    }
});

window.onload = function () {
    var stickies = $('.sticky');
    var dropdowns = $('select');

    var selects = [localStorage.getItem("branch"), localStorage.getItem("department"), localStorage.getItem("contact")];

    var company = localStorage.getItem("company");
    var first = localStorage.getItem("firstName");
    var last = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
    var phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
    var ext = localStorage.getItem("ext");
    var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    var help = localStorage.getItem("help");

    var stickiesArr = [company, first, last, phone, ext, email, help];

    for (var i = 0; i < stickiesArr.length; i++) {
        if (stickiesArr[i] != null) {
            stickies[i].value = stickiesArr[i];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        if (selects[i] != null) {
            dropdowns[i].value = selects[i];
        }
    }
    //this allows the wipe out of all data on a page refresh,
    //but clicking on "new shape" will maintain the data
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

This code works flawlessly in Chrome, but the page refresh in IE and Firefox fails to clear the localStorage. Am I doing something wrong for the localStorage to clear across multiple browsers?

### Edit

I have tried using `window.location.clear()`, and for good measure, `localSession.clear()`.

Comment: I don't see any outstanding errors in the syntax, do you have a fiddle? Or any console errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21156133/379855

Comment: There are no console errors in any browser. I'll try to create a dumbed down fiddle.

Comment: @Donal That may explain the IE11, but what about FireFox? If it's happening across multiple browsers, I'm led to believe this is possibly a coding issue rather than a required IE11 patch (though I will look into that).

Comment: @DrewKennedy Have you tried calling: window.localStorage.clear()

Comment: @Donal Yes. I will update my title and OP to reflect this. My mistake.

Comment: Why are you using localStorage if you don't want the data to be stored across page loads? seems a little counter-intuitive, or, wrong tool for the job, to me.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between the `location.reload()` that your span click does, and a refresh?!

Comment: @Bergi I'm guessing very little if any. I will admit ignorance to a resolution if this is the case. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finally get it to work. Part of the problem was the call of:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { (...) }
```

`FireFox` and `IE11` both were having trouble with this anonymous function call. I had to change my `on.click` event to:

```
$('#new-shape').on('click', function () {
    var stickies = $('.sticky');

    localStorage.setItem("branch", $('#00NL0000003INTJ').val());
    localStorage.setItem("department", $('#00NL0000003I0Ux').val());
    localStorage.setItem("contact", $('#00NL0000003INUC').val());

    localStorage.setItem("company", stickies[0].value);
    localStorage.setItem("firstName", stickies[1].value);
    localStorage.setItem("lastName", stickies[2].value);
    localStorage.setItem("phone", stickies[3].value);
    localStorage.setItem("ext", stickies[4].value);
    localStorage.setItem("email", stickies[5].value);
    localStorage.setItem("help", stickies[6].value);
});
```

And my `window.onload` anonymous function call had to be slightly reconfigured to:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var stickies = $('.sticky');
    var dropdowns = $('select');
    var selects = [localStorage.getItem("branch"), localStorage.getItem("department"), localStorage.getItem("contact")];

    var company = localStorage.getItem("company");
    var first = localStorage.getItem("firstName");
    var last = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
    var phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
    var ext = localStorage.getItem("ext");
    var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    var help = localStorage.getItem("help");

    var localStorageArr = [company, first, last, phone, ext, email, help];

    //input fields sticky
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorageArr.length; i++) {
        stickies[i].value = localStorageArr[i];
    }

    //dropdown fields sticky
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        if (selects[i] != null) {
            dropdowns[i].value = selects[i];
        } else {
            dropdowns[i].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    //fixing textarea
    if (help === null) {
        stickies[6].value = "";
    }
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Some hacky workarounds, but the results are now working as desired.