# IE 11 Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am getting an error in internet explorer 11

> "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" on
>   line

```
if (window.localStorage.length !== 0)
```

it works fine on chrome and Firefox, not sure whats causing it

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        // test to see if brouser supports storeage api
        var bSupportsLocal = (('localStorage' in window) && window.localStorage !== null );

        if (!bSupportsLocal) {
            document.getElementById('infoform').innerHTML = "<p> Sorry, This browser does not suport local storage. </p>";
            return;
        }

        if (window.localStorage.length !== 0) {
        document.getElementById('firstName').value = window.localStorage.getItem('firstName');
        $.mobile.navigate("#benefits-facts");
        }
    }

    function storeLocalContent(fName) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('firstName', fName);

        }

        function clearLocalContent(strToStore) {
            window.localStorage.clear();

            }

    window.onload = initialize;
    </script>
```

Comment: didi you try to remove one equal sign? window.localStorage !== null

Comment: if i remove one equal sign i get "Sorry, This browser does not support local storage."

Comment: I believe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155137/javascript-localstorage-object-broken-in-ie11-on-windows-7/21156133#21156133

Comment: that is not the problem, I am running the latest versions of IE 11

Comment: @brodster Are you perhaps [accessing the page with `file://`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie)? Or, have you checked the [document mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406036.aspx) that's in use? The page may be running under a compatibility mode that doesn't support web storage.

Answer (score 1):

I thought in IE `window.localStorage` is undefined initially. You are checking is `localStorage` in the `window` and its not `null`. So `bSupportLocal` is setting to true. Its executing `window.localStorage.length` statement. Undefined.length causing error. 
   Here is the code

```
     var bSupportsLocal = window['localStorage'] || '';
```

If localStorage is having some value it will assign to bSupportsLocal, otherwise it is assigned with empty string.