# using "localStorage.setItem" Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, local-storage, internet-explorer-11

I want to use `localStorage.setItem` in internet Explorer 11,

I tried like:

```
<script>
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
</script>
```

but in IE console I see:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'setItem' of undefined or null reference.

I also tried the [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816684/12550657) like:

```
<script>
!localStorage && (l = location, p = l.pathname.replace(/(^..)(:)/, "$1$$"), (l.href = l.protocol + "//127.0.0.1" + p));

if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    alert(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
} else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}
</script>
```

but then I get:

> [image]

Comment: Should work. https://caniuse.com/#search=webstorage

Comment: The error page is not likely due to JS errors

Comment: Your link is not a good candidate for testing localStorage

Comment: This page works in IE11 http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Comment: @mplungjan Great links but still doesn't work, I tried `window.webstorage.setItem('key', 'value');` then I get `Unable to get property 'setItem' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Your IT department can block localStorage usage in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Please check this option in IE 11, if this option is disabled, storage object will be undefined in IE:

  1. Click the "Tools" menu and choose "Internet Options".
  2. Click on the tab labeled "Advanced".
  3. Check the box for "**Enable DOM Storage**".
  4. Click "Apply", click "OK".

[image]

- `localstorage` can't work with `file://` protocal, you need to run the page through http protocal.
- There might be [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155137/javascript-localstorage-object-broken-in-ie11-on-windows-7/21156133#21156133) with `localstorage` in old version of IE 11 in win7/win8, please make sure you have installed the latest update.